# Как отсортировать строки случайным образом при запросе к базе данных используя EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite?

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, sqlite, entity-framework

Хочу получить определенное количество случайных строк из таблицы в базе данных.
В интернете нашел такой код:

```
db.Bloggers.Where(blogger =>
                    blogger.Thematics.Contains(user.TemporaryCategory.NameNormalized) &&
                    blogger.PhoneNumber != null).OrderBy(_ => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(count).ToList(),
```

Однако получаю ошибку:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(b => b.Thematics.Contains(__user_TemporaryCategory_NameNormalized_0) && b.PhoneNumber != null)
> .OrderBy(b => Guid.NewGuid())' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Guid.NewGuid' failed.

В SQLite уже есть встроенная функция Random, с помощью которой происходит случайная сортировка:

```
ORDER BY RANDOM();
```

Как именно я могу отсортировать строки случайным образом используя Entity Framework?

Comment: А если `Where` убрать из запроса?

Comment: Ничего не изменяется.